# "error unmounting /dev/sda1:target is busy" when I try to resize a partition

Tags: partitioning

I want to resize the disk with GParted, but the resize button is not active. When I try to do it from the disk application, I get the error:

```
error unmounting /dev/sda1:target is busy (udisks-error-quark,14)
```

What should I do?

[image: parameters set in Resize dialog but button is greyed out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Key next to the partition in gparted indicates that the drive is mounted (in use). So, you need to "unmount" them to be resized.
2. You cannot unmount root partition if you are booting from it.
3. It is usually better to do partition changes from a Live media/pendrive

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you this helped.